# What do you use to manage your shell history?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, command-history, tmux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)
>   [Can I easily search my history across many screen windows?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/can-i-easily-search-my-history-across-many-screen-windows)

I rely on my shell history a lot, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and arrow keys and I `grep` through it often.

The problem with with history is if you have more than one session, like if you are using `tmux` or `screen` or you open multiple terminal windows or tabs, you would lose all your history except the one you close last.

I thought, there should be a solution for this, I bet others had the same problem and either they use a replacement for history or use a tool to manage history properly.

Comment: See [Can I easily search my history across many windows?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/can-i-easily-search-my-history-across-many-screen-windows)